# JFrame component: "Drag-Bar"?

Tags: java, swing

I would like to know if there is something like a dragable bar as a component for a JFrame. They are used in windows for eg. changing the sound volume or the screen brightness. But is there something similar in swing?

Thank you!

Comment: [How to Use Sliders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe JSlider does what you want. Here's the documentation from Oracle:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html